# Weird answer edit revertable?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I edited this answer and then @jonsca edited my edit by removing a section. 
As can be seen at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/9781/revisions , he removed:

> . Also, note: **You cannot** use more than 1 one $5 No-Rush reward and an instant discount on the **same** order, **and** the order has to be **over $35**.

and he didn't add *anything*.

The edit summary doesn't match this action *at all*; it reads:

> Correction/update and add Digital Rewards and Prime Now Rewards promo credit and expiration lookup info.

Since the edit summary doesn't match, I'm tempted to just put back the removed text (which improves the answer) and jon or whomever can always attempt to further improve it.  Does jon being a mod, or any documented rule/guideline make that a no-no?  Not that I know of.

Comment: The edit messages get carried over from whomever initially made the edit (I hit the "improve" button in the UI), actually.  In terms of the actual edit, I removed what I perceived to be "extra" information that didn't pertain to "How do I check my promotional credit with Amazon?"  Editing the information back in is definitely not a "no-no" by any stretch and all of the above was no slight on you. I apologize if it came across that way.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  There no "improve" button in the UI, at least not for my account.  There's actually only an 'edit' *text link*, but its help text is  'revise and improve this post'.  I'm curious what your UI looks like.  Mine also does not carry over an edit summary from one edit to the next; it starts with a blank edit summary (at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/9781/edit. )
Anyway your edit's edit summary doesn't match. In fact I just noticed it's a copy of my edit summary.   And...

Comment: And thanks for the apology!  I was ... perturbed.  (I noted:)
"Also, all the fine print on the Prime Now Rewards (which I think I summarized quite concisely) makes them close to worthless," no?  So my goal with that text was to add information about that, as I thought it would likely be relevant to someone wondering "How do I check my promotional credit with Amazon?".  Perhaps a better place for that info would be a separate Q&A : [[Q: Are Amazon's Prime Now Rewards offered in exchange for accepting slow shipping useful? A: Fine print makes them close to worthless because.... ]]  Folks agree?

Comment: The "Improve and Edit" button is in the Suggested Edit queue UI.  That's where edits get sent when the user in question has less than 2000 reputation.  Once you are over 2K, there's no longer a requirement for an edit summary, so upon improving the edit and leaving no edit summary, the dialog autofills the prior explanation in rather than the boilerplate "26 characters modified" or whatever the system generates.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Bad UI!

Answer (score 2):

There is also no reply to the comment I had added to the answer I edited.  Oh, and here's the fine print upon which I based my summary:

> Use your Prime Now rewards to place orders for FREE 2-hour delivery on the Prime Now app or at PrimeNow.com for groceries delivered to your door. We'll automatically apply the reward at checkout, limit one promotion per order, limit one $5 reward per Prime Now order. Offer redemption requires customers to be in eligible Prime Now U.S. ZIP codes.

Since the Prime Now rewards can only be used on FREE 2-hour delivery, that means the order must top $35.

I'm still considering whether to reword and restore a clearer version my addition, or do nothing.  For now, the feedback leads me to do nothing further.